# OGB dataset, I can not import "PygNodePropPredDataset" from "ogb.nodeproppred"

Tags: python, deep-learning, importerror

I can not import "PygNodePropPredDataset" from "ogb.nodeproppred". I have installed the ogb by "pip3 install ogb"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of where the problem occur

Comment: sorry, the code snippet is "from ogb.nodeproppred import PygNodePropPredDataset", and the problem is "ImportError: cannot import name 'PygNodePropPredDataset'"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to handle the pytorch version manually, you can use following snippet:

```bash
TORCH=$(python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch.__version__)')
echo $TORCH
pip3 install -q torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}.html
pip3 install -q torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}.html
pip3 install -q git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git
```

it's a bash equivalent of jupyter-notebook code:

```
# Install required packages.
import os
import torch
os.environ['TORCH'] = torch.__version__
print(torch.__version__)

!pip install -q torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}.html
!pip install -q torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}.html
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git
```

taken from [PyG's Graph Classification with Graph Neural Networks](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I8a0DfQ3fI7Njc62__mVXUlcAleUclnb?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [this pyg issue](https://github.com/snap-stanford/ogb/issues/115#issuecomment-797415959).
It says that you are probably missing required deppendencies: *torch_geometric*, *torch_scatter* and *torch_sparse*.
You can install them by running:

```
pip3 install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.12.0+11.6.html
pip3 install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.12.0+11.6.html
pip3 install torch-geometric==1.12.0
```

You can change the package version and Cuda version if desired. [This installation guide](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html) can be helpful for finding compatible versions.